# How can I combine multiple records and sum the Amount row, so there is only one record after?

Tags: mysql

The query I'm using to sum is:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) as `Amount`
FROM balances
WHERE User_ID='$user_id' AND `Wallet_ID` = '$idtw'
```

I need to combine all the rows so there is only one record in the database, because while sum works for display, when updating the balance upon a withdrawal it's practically impossible.

Comment: Why don't you just display the last record instead of the first record?

Comment: @DamienBlack, i thought about that, but then i decided that i would like to keep table population minimum for performance reasons. the more rows to search the slower the query(imho)

Comment: Why not update the record?

Comment: @Snoburnt, because the records are created from a deposit script. if a record doesn't exist the update query fails. i tried to check `num_rows` first, but it was greatly decreasing performance, since the deposit query iterates over a list of jsonrpc connections and retrieves deposits, adds them to the db, then on the next go of the script if a deposit is confirmed it is to a `Paid=1 flag` and mapped to the balance table.

Comment: Can you tell be what happens if a user deposits a bitcoin, and then deposits another one? How is that represented?

Comment: Obviously I didn't get it right. Could you try to phrase your question more clearly? Your code doesn't make much sense. Does the user have a history of balances (for each currency) or an aggregation of balances? What do you want to query from the database?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and schema, maybe going along with your use-case?

Comment: @ damien black. if the user deposits a coin, then deposits another one there is a separate record for each, however the balance is updated via update queries once the deposit has been confirmed. the only time it fails is when the user has a previous balance that is zero for some odd bizarre reason. thats why i came up with the ajax on the account page to delete rows where balance=0, so that the query wont fail. i think i may have the best solution for it. i'm not sure. obviously i would like a little more than just wildly deleting rows at will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, the user has n-balance records and you're interested in the sum of his balances:

```
SELECT SUM(balance) FROM balances WHERE user_id=? GROUP BY user_id;
```

---

Obviously I didn't get it right. Then I try to understand that your balance relation is a history record and you're only interested in the current balance (=last record). I would suggest to give your records versions and keep track which is the current record. A scheme like this might help:

```
CurrentBalance(user_id, symbol, version)
Balance(user_id, symbol, version, amount)
```

Your CurrentBalance gives you the latest version for a given symbol and user and you can easily track your balance records, read your current balance from Balance.

The content of your relations might look like this:

```
 CurrentBalance = {
     (1, "BTC", 3),
     (2, "BTC", 4),
     (1, "USD", 2),
 }

 Balance = {
     (1, "BTC", 1, 1.123),
     (1, "BTC", 2, 0),
     (1, "BTC", 3, 4.234),  // current balance for user 1 and symbol BTC
     (2, "BTC", 1, 1.00),
     (2, "BTC", 2, 1.11),
     (2, "BTC", 3, 0),
     (2, "BTC", 4, 5.123),  // current balance for user 2 and symbol BTC
     (1, "USD", 1, 11.11), 
     (1, "USD", 2, 10.12),  // current balance for user 1 and symbol USD
 }
```

When you're updating the current balance of a user you simply increase the version
for the user and his symbol in the `CurrentBalance` relation and add a new record
with that new version to the `Balance` relation.

Comment: unfortunately this will not work in a trading platform because the act of trading and withdrawing removes from the balances(via update queries). allowing tons of balance records for a single user on a single coin is beyond inneficient and lazy, and requires greatly rewriting my code base.

Comment: Then I simply don't get your question.

Comment: After a month or so struggling with my method, i ultimately realized the rightness of your answer. so even though i said you were wrong, it turns out your suggestion is not only better, its the only secure way to track the history. thanks for your posts, i get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Just make an `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`to grab the last record instead.

Comment: Ok, i'll take this suggestion as well. I still feel like is an incomplete solution, so i will hold out for a bit more complete question. i'm looking for something that is a good blend of Safe, Reliable, Functional, and Fast.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is every time someone "withdraws his remaining bitcoin" you, instead of update the credits to 0, you can, for example delete the row. So, the user have no rows on that table means 0 credits.
This is good only if you have only a very simple table without additional fields. (a table that saves only the user_id and the amount)

Comment: i ended up going with my own solution, which was to remove the duplicate balance issue completely. unfortunately, this created more problems, as now the trade engine instead duplicates the amount instead of the db record.